# Is there a way to run IDL code without paying for license?

Tags: ide, idl-programming-language

I have to convert some code from IDL to Python as a part of a project. The problem is that to convert it I need to learn IDL first and I can't seem to find a compiler for it nor can I find any tutorials.
Is there any other way to run the code?
Any compiler even if they are trial versions that work for like a day would help too.
Thanks

Comment: Welcome! What did you try before you posted? SO has [a helpful guide on how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Wikipedia lists GDL under "See Also" and was the first hit in a [search for "free IDL programming language"](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=free+IDL+programming+language).

Answer (score 1):

Try the open source version of IDL, [GDL](https://github.com/gnudatalanguage/gdl). It is a separate open source implementation of IDL, so not 100% compatible, but pretty close now.